# How to power my 120v 60hz CRT and classic gaming consoles in 230v 50hz countries

Tags: ps2, nintendo-64

I'm moving to Ireland next month. I have a small collection of classic gaming consoles and a Sony Trinitron that I play them on.

My CRT is a Sony Trinitron KV-27FS100 which requires 120v 60hz and Ireland is 230v 50hz.

I use it to play PS2 and N64 / watch standard definition NTSC movies.

Is there a good solution to keep my stuff working?

Comment: Are you sure your TV doesn't have a switch-mode power supply that can support 230v? Or does the input label explicitly state 110-120v?

Comment: The sticking point is really the 60hz required for NTSC

Answer (score 1):

Most consumer electronics operate within a certain range of voltage.

The Sony Trinitron KV-27FS100 model states it requires 120v 60hz, but works fine at 110v 60hz as well. The KV-27FS100 requires 185w to run.

You will need a frequency/power converter. [The Hercules model from KCC Scientific should meet your needs perfectly](https://www.kccscientific.com/product/hercules-frequency-converter/).

You're PS2 and N64 will work fine with a run-of-the-mill step-down transformer that takes 230v 50hz and outputs 115v 50hz.